# ASUS server power troubles, not turning out, on and off. Etc

Tags: hardware, electrical-power, asus

So, I live in a country where power isn't exactly reliable (210vac usually, with almost constant changes) and I am working with a school that doesn't exactly have a large budget (yet, still growing yearly)

We got donated an old ASUS TS700-E8-RS8 and it was working well for about two months, and since at the time we weren't needing it yet and we didn't have a UPS (we do now, but it can't regulate the power, we've got a new one we're installing now that can.) I turned it off after every time I configured it a little further.

Here's where the problem started: around 2 months after it was donated it stopped starting, instead it would, 1.turn on and start the fans up LOUD, 2. Turn off. 3. Repeat the process over and over again.

So, after that happened I took it to my house (in town where the power is better) and it booted perfectly! I installed Windows server on it (the HDDs had been corrupted) and ran it perfectly for around 4 weeks. At that point I figured my problem was over so I took it back to the school, heck was I wrong. So it doesn't start again.

Today, I decided to take another look at it and do some debugging (I'd left it for a while because I'm ticked off with it.) and I figured out the following (with some pictures).

We have two power units (one redundant), here's a picture of them:
[we'll call this number one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NpEa.jpg)
[and this number two](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rcIV.jpg)
So:

1. When number one is plugged into mains but not the server (they're    removable btw) the green light shows and the orange (error) light shows immediately.
2. When number two is plugged into mains but the the server the green light shows, but NOT the orange light.
3. When I plug number one into the server (with mains on) immediately the fan speeds up to hurricane speeds (really fast, and loud) and both lights stay on, the server with flash on for half a second then stop, until I press the power button again.
4. When I plug number two into the server (with mains on) the orange error light comes on, and the server immediately starts turning on and off at a medium rare, and then after a few seconds starts going on and off very fast.
5. When I plug both into the server (with mains on) the orange lights and green lights are on, both fans rev up to hurricane force, and the server starts its own fans and stays steadily on, but does not boot or give any beep codes (no ram in it so it should if it were working, it did previously).

So yeah, sorry for the really long post but this has been quite an.. Experience. So, I'm wondering two things 1. Why on the face of the earth is this happening? (Preferably in simpler speech, doesn't have to be too dumbed down though). And 2. Will regulating the power with a UPS help? Or should I replace the power packs...

Thanks for your time!

-Asher

EDIT 1: The UPS that we're still working on installing (it's hard wired so we have to get the stuff for it) is an APC SURT8000XLI (the three phase model, it has three model "codes" on the back) 40 amp model.

EDIT 2: OKAY! So, I took it home (these kinda better power there) and I plugged it in, the first couple tries did wierd things, but every try after then has done this:
1. Orange error lights and high speed fans on PSUs
2. I press the power button quickly on server
3. Orange lights turn green, fans slow down, and cup fans and case fans startup. 
4. Another error (that I already knew about, it's the RAM), sooo good news? Kinda. Lol.

So, I think it's the power that's the issue, so once I fix the RAM I'll take it back to he school and try the exact same process I did above, maybe it'll help, otherwise I'm going to try the UPS next. Fun times!!

Comment: Btw, sorry for any problems with my post, I'm new here, but I'd love to hang around here more often, I love this stuff.

Comment: Does this still happen at your house? Or is it working if you plug it in at home? If it works: check the same setup with your newer UPS which regulates the current fluctuations. Maybe add the UPS details to your question (manufacturer, model number, and so on).

Comment: I have yet to take it home again, bit of a hassle, but it'd be worth the trouble, so I'll get back to you guys with that info when I've done it (within a couple days hopefully)

Comment: Phew, why such a huge UPS? I certainly hope it's not only for that one server :)

Comment: Gosh no, it was part of an absolutely awesome donation from an extremely large company near us (one of the largest companies in the world, they don't want the donation known public tho, sorry). But we've got some switches and security appliances on it as well (still over powered tho, lol)